# how to use pagination on product listing React Native

Tags: react-native

I am creating react native app. on app category page i am fetching data and from live url in json form and post it into product page.
fetching data code:-

```
handlePressProduct(id) {
    var url='http://www.furnitureinfashion.net/menu_category_listing.php?cat_id=';  
    fetch(url+id, {
    method: 'GET'
    }).then((response) => { return response.json() } )
    .then((responseJson) => {
    console.log(responseJson);
    Actions.product({data:responseJson}) 
    })    
}
```

on product page i am getting data like this:-

```
        {this.props.data.map((dataImage,Index1)=>
        <View key={Index1}>     
        {dataImage['ProductId'] != undefined && (
                <View style={productStyle.homeimg1}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.handlePressProduct.bind(this,dataImage['ProductId'])}>
                        <Image source={{uri: uri+dataImage['Image']}} style={{width: 130, height: 130}} />
                        <Text style={productStyle.title}> {dataImage['ProductName']}</Text>                         
                        <Text style={productStyle.shopbutton}>View Details</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>     
                    {dataImage['Options'] != '' &&(
                    <Text style={productStyle.cartbutton} >Select Option</Text> 
                    )}  
                    {dataImage['Options'] == '' &&(
                    <Text style={productStyle.cartbutton} >Add to cart</Text>
                    )}
                    <Text> RRP{dataImage['RRPPrice']}</Text>
                    <Text> Our Price{dataImage['OurPrice']}</Text>
                    <Text style={productStyle.buymorebutton} >Buy & Save More Today</Text>
                    <Text style={productStyle.shiptext} >Free Shipping</Text>
                </View>
                )}
        </View>
        )}
```

in array product data is too large so, i want to add pagination on product page. but i don't know how to do?

Comment: it'll be better if you made the pagination on the server.

Comment: sorry, i can't understand .

Comment: Pagination should be done on the server & then you ask the server for the first page let's say you need to get 8 item by 8 items.

so the request will be http://www.furnitureinfashion.net/menu_category_listing.php?page=1

page equal the page you want & with every user scroll you send a request to the server to get the next page,

there's a function call onScrollEndReached in List which can be used

Comment: let me try this. i think you are right .

Comment: but how can i add pagination buttons at the bottom like prev 1 2 3 next

Comment: you can get how many pages you have from the server then render the buttons

Comment: i think i did same for filters. thank you soo much.  i got it